# Trigger not working with update query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables tbl_date and tbl_fine with ret and fine columns respectively. I want that the fine should increase by 1 whenever the system date is greater than the ret. I tried to make a trigger but it is giving an error. The dbms is MySQL. Fine is of integer type and ret is of date type. Please tell me what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
   create trigger t1
-> before insert on tbl_date
-> for each row
-> begin
-> declare retv date;
-> select ret into @retv from tbl_date;
-> while(curdate()>@retv)
-> update tbl_fine set fine=fine+1;
-> end while;
-> end;
-> //
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update tbl_fine set fine=fine+1;
end while;
end' at line 8

Create table tbl_date(ret date);
Create table tbl_fine(fine integer(4) default 0);

Comment: Here `retv != @retv`

Comment: Please explain what's wrong.